# The relationship between derivatives and normal function

Tags: derivative, calculus

Let f’ be a differentiable function, and suppose that f(2x)=3f(x) for all x. Prove that f’(2x)=3/2f’(x).

Answer (score 0):

We have f(2x) = 3f(x), if we apply the derivate in both sides of the equality, then:

[image: d/dx]

In the left side of the equality, we have to derivate the function and multiply it to the derivate of the function's argument:

[image]

In the right side, we have a product.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), when you have a derivation of a product, the result is as follow:

[image]

Followin this rule, we get:

[image]

Now we have:

[image]

Which take us to:

[image]

Images generated with [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)